# '@' printed out in a ctime based function

Tags: c++, function, time, header-files

I am developing a header file which has a function to print the date out.
The following does the above:

```
    char Date(string date_format){
    if(date_format == "gg\dd\yyyy"){
                time_t t = time(0);
    struct tm * now = localtime( & t );
    cout << (now->tm_mday) << '/'
     << (now->tm_mon + 01) << '/'
     << (now->tm_year + 1900);
    }
    if(date_format == "mm\dd\yyyy"){
                time_t t = time(0);
    struct tm * now = localtime( & t );
    cout << (now->tm_mon + 01) << '/'
    << (now->tm_mday) << '/'
    << (now->tm_year + 1900);
    }
```

So, to use this function in a .cpp file you'll have to write

```
    cout << Date("dd\mm\yyyy") << endl;
```

It will print out "6/5/2016"
And it will print the italian date format, if i set the english one(mm\dd\yyyy)it prints out a tilde at the end of the date:
5/6/2016@
Maybe it's a dumb error, of perhaps is because of the backslahed which makes the compiler think i am trying to use escape sequence like '\n', but no escape sequence with '\m' or '\d' exist so i thought it wasn't a proble.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strings like `"dd\mm\yyyy"` are definitely going to cause you lots of problems, because yes, the compiler is going to try to interpret escape sequences `\m` and `\y`.

Comment: Backlashes must be escaped in C and C++ string literals `"mm\\dd\\yy"`.  However, that doesn't explain the `@` character.  The problem is somewhere in code that you aren't showing.

Comment: Suggest you take a look at the C `strftime` function.

Comment: If your compiler doesn't diagnose `"\d"`, it is nonconforming. It is a syntax error according to ISO C.   All the possible character escape sequences are described by a grammar, and `\d` doesn't match that grammar.  (Are you ignoring warnings from your compiler? An ISO C  required diagnostic can be given as a warning: even a syntax error.)

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a lot of problem.

1) you pass the format "dd\mm\yyyy", but this format isn't checked in `Date()` (you check "gg\dd\yyyy" and "mm\dd\yyyy")

2) your function is declared as a funtion returning a `char` but there isn't `return` in it

3) as suggested by Kaz, you should escape every `'\'` doubling it (so "gg\\dd\\yyyy", "mm\\dd\\yyyy", etc.)

4) I think you should write a function that create and return an `std::string`, avoiding to use output streams. Your actual function write in `std::cout` but return (do not return, see point 2) a char; what the meaning of the returned value? If `Data()` write in `std::cout()`, you should use it in this way

```
Data("dd\\mm\\yyyy");
std::cout << std::endl;
```

If `Data()` return a `std::string`, so you can write

```
std::cout << Data("dd\\mm\\yyyy") << std::endl;
```

I suggest that `Data()` should return a `std::string` so you can use it with other streams; `std::cerr`, by example

```
std::cerr << Data("dd\\mm\\yyyy") << std::endl;
```

5) there is no need to duplicate the `time()`/`localtime()` part; it's equal in both cases

I propose the following version

```
std::string Date (std::string const & format)
 {
   std::ostringstream  oss;

   time_t t = time(0);
   tm * now = localtime( & t );

   if ( "gg\\dd\\yyyy" == format )
      oss << (now->tm_mday) << '/'
         << (now->tm_mon + 01) << '/'
         << (now->tm_year + 1900);
   else if ( "mm\\dd\\yyyy" == format )
      oss << (now->tm_mon + 01) << '/'
         << (now->tm_mday) << '/'
         << (now->tm_year + 1900);
   // else if .... (other formats?)
   else
      oss << "unrecognized format";

   return oss.str();
 }
```

or, if you're using C++11 or C++14, you can use `std::to_string()`, avoiding `std::ostringstream`

```
std::string Date (std::string const & format)
 {
   std::string  str;

   time_t t = time(0);
   tm * now = localtime( & t );

   if ( "gg\\dd\\yyyy" == format )
      str = std::to_string(now->tm_mday) + "/"
         + std::to_string(now->tm_mon + 01) + "/"
         + std::to_string(now->tm_year + 1900);
   else if ( "mm\\dd\\yyyy" == format )
      str = std::to_string(now->tm_mon + 01) + "/"
         + std::to_string(now->tm_mday) + "/"
         + std::to_string(now->tm_year + 1900);
   // else if .... (other formats?)
   else
      str = "unrecognized format";

   return str;
 }
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English

Comment: Your point #2 is undoubtedly where the extra trailing character is coming from -- when the indeterminate return value is sent to the output.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: yes: a random char.